# R ggplot automatic recalculation with geom tile when subsetting

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am attempting to create heat maps with a large data set that has several factors. I'd like to get a birds eye view first, by plotting the heat map of all values and all factors. THEN, I'd like to subset the heat map plot by a variety of factors - but have `ggplot2::geom_tile` re-calculate the heat map so it plots the relative abundance based on whatever factors I've subsampled.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#Test data
df <- data.frame(
   Measurement = c(1:30),
   CA = rep(rnorm(30, mean=20, sd=5)),
   TX = rep(rnorm(30, mean=18, sd=5)),
   NY = rep(rnorm(30, mean=34, sd=2))
 )
df.melt <- melt(df,id = c("Measurement"))
```

Basic heat map plot code. My actual data includes several factors/columns from which I want to pull data for various comparisons.

```
#Basic plot
ggplot(data = df.melt, 
       aes(x = variable, y = Measurement, colors = value, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("lightyellow", "darkred"))
```

I want the output colors to correspond to relative abundance by measurement. So I can look at Relative changes across CA, TX, and NY. This would be my "Base plot".

```
df.melt.reabun <- df.melt %>% group_by(Measurement) %>% 
    mutate(RelAbun = value/sum(value))
df.melt.reabun <- as.data.frame(df.melt.reabun)

#New plot with relative abundance
ggplot(data = df.melt.reabun, 
       aes(x = variable, y = Measurement, colors = RelAbun, fill = RelAbun)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("lightyellow", "darkred"))
```

What I also want to do is be able to re-plot however I want and the relative abundance to automatically calculate within ggplot tile.

```
#Assign plot object  
heat <- ggplot(data = df.melt.reabun, 
               aes(x = variable, y = Measurement, colors = RelAbun, fill = RelAbun)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "black")+ 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("lightyellow", "darkred"))

#Select variable to subset data
alt <- c("CA", "TX")

#Subset ggplot object
heat %+% subset(df.melt.reabun, variable %in% alt)
```

### But this output is incorrect, because it is only showing relative abundance from the calculation that included CA, TX, and NY.

I want the relative abundance to re-calculate every time I subset the df to  plot at this step: `heat %+% subset()`

I have a feeling I can smoothly combine `group_by` and `geom_tile` to do this automatically.. but I can't quite figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. I have MANY MANY combinations of heat maps I want to look at and I do NOT want to re-calculate the relative abundance "manually" each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally advisable to do your data wranglings *before* passing the data frame to ggplot. In this case, something like the following could work:

```
subsetFun <- function(df, var.filter){
  return(df %>% 
           filter(variable %in% var.filter) %>%
           group_by(Measurement) %>%
           mutate(RelAbun = value / sum(value)) %>%
           ungroup())
}

heat %+% subsetFun(df.melt.reabun, alt)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks! I will work on adapting code so processing is ahead of ggplot work. That is better. Always looking for ways to simplify code.